# How to make bootstrap button responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap button having **width** of **128px** and **height** of **30px**.

When I resize my browser window, the buttons are not responsive.

What am I missing?

```css
.common_btn{
   width: 128px; 
   height: 30px; 
   float: right; 
   margin: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn m-b-xs w-xs btn-danger common_btn "  style="float:left;">New Contact</button>
<button class="btn m-b-xs w-xs btn-danger common_btn " >Delete</button>
<button class="btn m-b-xs w-xs btn-dark common_btn" >Save</button>
```

Comment: not responsive means? It will not take full width?

Comment: i have updated question. when i have 3 buttons, one of them is on left side and i resize it then it is  not responsive.

Answer (score 4):

For this you can specify the width of the buttons by using media queries.

*/ For tablet and below device/*
@media (max-width: 768px) {
...
}

Answer (score 0):

Use a percentage(%) instead of set pixels.

Example:

```
width: 20%;
```

Answer (score 0):

change fixed width size in to %

```
.common_btn{
   width: calc( 100% - 30px) /* take total container width and reduce 30px */
   height: 30px; 
   float: right; 
   margin: 0 15px;
}
```